# Remove MSU Beta badge

Tags: bug, status-declined, badges

Meta Super User never went through a painful creation process. Like Athena, it just popped into the world fully formed and ready for business. (Yes, Jeff Atwood is basically Zeus in this analogy. No, we're not going to pursue that thought.)

MSU still has a "Beta" badge listed on its badge page, but nobody has ever earned such a badge, and nobody ever will. I request that it be stricken.

I have submitted a similar request for Server Fault [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/817/remove-msf-beta-badge).
It seems that [a similar request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/wrong-text-for-beta-badge-on-meta/11027#11027) for Meta Stack Overflow was granted last year.

Answer (score 3):

Let's also have the following badges removed, which aren't attainable on Meta.SU either:

- Precognitive (no Area 51 proposal)
- Epic (no reputation)
- Legendary (no reputation)
- Talkative (there is no Meta chat)
- Altruist (no bounties)
- Benefactor (no bounties)
- Investor (no bounties)
- Promoter (no bounties)
- Proofreader ([no suggested edits](https://meta.superuser.com/q/3920/22317))

Comment: Not sure whether *Reviewer* is attainable on MSU.

Comment: [Separate Meta topic about the reputaiton badges](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4265/reputation-related-badges-exist-and-are-attainable-on-msu).

Comment: You can still suggest edits to tag wikis, though...