# Reputation related badges exist and are attainable on MSU

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, meta

Quoting any child meta site's `/reputation`:

> Reputation on this per-site meta is derived entirely from the main site; nothing to show.

Which is consistent with what's shown as part of the user info: main site reputation.

Additionally, `/users` does not have a *reputation* page, it instead displays *activity* which counts upvotes and accepts:

[image]

On a user's profile, there is no *reputation* tab (first screenshot), as on the main site (second screenshot, fourth from the right).

[image]

[image]

---

On the other hand, reputation badges exist and are attainable:

- [Legendary](https://meta.superuser.com/badges/43/legendary)
- [Epic](https://meta.superuser.com/badges/42/epic)
- [Mortarboard](https://meta.superuser.com/badges/41/mortarboard)

That last badge has been awarded *five times* so far on Meta.SU, [most recently in August](https://meta.superuser.com/users/80670/simon-sheehan?tab=activity&sort=badges)

---

The badges on "reputation-less" child meta sites make no sense at all from a user's POV. While there are badges, and they can be awarded, there is neither a *reputation* tab in the user profile, nor a `/reputation` history. I don't believe for one second that this, *as a whole*, was deliberately designed this way, and if it was, it should be changed.

**This should be fixed e.g. by completely deleting the relevant badges from the child meta sites.**

Answer (score 1):

You might not get actual reputation on meta, but your posts still collect the upvotes and downvotes. And while the wording is off, that's still the same engine running the badge process.

The normal vote actions, compared against the accepted answers and bounties, still play the same as if they were giving visible or actual rep changes.

Comment: The tags *exist* by design on MSU? While you explain the observed behaviour nicely, you're not making a case for continuing it.

Comment: You don't want to know when other SU meta users get plenty of upvotes on postings in here that they keep bumping their heads on how agreeable they are?

Comment: So you prefer I file a bug against meta `/reputation` page instead? It's one or the other, and this one is consistent with what i believe is the intent of meta reputation behavior. // Aside from that, Reputation is a crap measure for meta, since the vote weights from the main site only make sense for support questions.

Comment: Reputation badges work the same way, they just count based on the upvotes. So even if you don't see the rep, it's still counting the upvotes as normally attached to work out when Mortarboard, Epic and Barney Stinson qualify.

Comment: What you write is exactly my point. It either has rep support, including `/reputation`, privileges and badges, or it doesn't. The current intermediate state is noticeably broken: I inherit privileges from the main site, don't actually have visible rep here and cannot access the reputation history of `/reputation` (which would also show a progress report on rep cap badges), ***but** can get rep cap badges*. Having an explanation of broken behavior doesn't make it "not a bug". It simply means that the cause of said broken behavior is known. It's the same with the 0.58/57% issue.