# The 'Precognitive' badge should be removed

Tags: feature-request, badges

No one has earned the [`Precognitive`](https://superuser.com/badges/94/precognitive) badge and no one can ever earn it.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.superuser.com/a/4263/22317).

Comment: By the way, is this deliberately tagged `discussion`? The title makes it more a `feature-request`/`support`/`bug` topic...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The badges are not per site. They are all the same on every site, and thus, newer sites will actually have this badge with members who have it.

Despite that, about 2 years ago it was [removed from Meta.StackOverflow.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/wrong-text-for-beta-badge-on-meta/11027#11027) We really should be getting it removed on all meta sites, and trilogy sites.

Comment: Actually, that the discussion you linked to was about removing the **Beta** badge, not the Precognitive badge.

Comment: @Synetech its along the same lines.

Comment: Yes, but only the Beta badge was removed; MetaSO still has a Precognitive badge.